# Quais são as diferenças entre Visibility.Hidden e Visibility.Collapsed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Quais são as diferenças entre as visibilidades `Visibility.Hidden` e `Visibility.Collapsed` do WPF?

Existem diferenças práticas ou teóricas entre *setar* o `Height` e o `Width` de um controle para **zero** e *setar* sua visibilidade para `Visibility.Hidden` ou `Visibility.Collapsed`? Se sim, quais seriam as diferenças para cada um dos dois modos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviamente ambos impedem que o elemento seja visualizado.

`Visibility.Hidden` reserva o espaço que o elemento ocupará no *layout*, assim nada será redesenhado a não ser nessa área. Fica tudo fixo no lugar, escondendo ou não. Apenas esconde, mas o elemento está lá.

`Visibility.Collapsed` não reserva o espaço e limpa do *layout*, podendo exigir redesenho de outros elementos para ajustar as posições. Ele *setará* a altura e o comprimento para zero e o elemento deixa de estar ali.

Se apenas mudar o `width` e `height` o elemento mudará o *layout*, igual ao `Collapsed`, mas o elemento continua presente, igual ao `Hidden`, mesmo que invisível, mantendo características de algo disponível, ativo. Por exemplo ele pode ganhar foco quando os controles vão mudando de elementos em navegação, provavelmente com <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Pode haver outras consequências. A não ser que deseje exatamente fazer o elemento sair da tela, tirando seu espaço, mas permaneça lá, é errado usar essa técnica.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

`Visibility.Hidden` torna o objeto invisível mas reserva o espaço dele no layout.

`Visibility.Collapsed` torna o objeto invisível e faz com que ele não ocupe nenhum espaço no layout.

Já setar o `Width`ou `Height` como zero eu não vejo muito sentido já que isso só tornaria mais difícil esconder e mostrar o elemento, pois para exibir novamente eu precisaria saber o tamanho que este elemento deve ter, sem contar os casos em que não se usa o `Width` e `Height` para definir o tamanho dos elementos.

Comment: Supondo que eu não precise mais mostrar o elemento, existiriam diferenças entre setar a altura e largura para zero e usar o `Collapsed`?

Comment: @ViníciusBrasil isso é complicado de dizer pois precisaria saber como o WPF trata os elementos, pois eu não sei se ele tentaria renderizar o elemento mesmo com tamanho zero, só consigo imaginar no caso do elemento poder ter foco, mesmo com tamanho zero ele ainda está visível então imagino que o foco possa ir parar nele ainda, o que não aconteceria se usasse o `Hidden`ou `Collapsed`